# How to handle System.IO.IOException in Java

Tags: java, c#, exception, jni4net

I'm using jni4net to bridge between Java program & a C# dll file which controls a hardware device. The device and PC are connected by a network cable and I'm trying to handle the cable unplugged case while Java program is retrieving data from the hardware device via C# dll, frequently.

When unplugged the network cable, following exception is thrown by C# which is to be caught at Java side. But it's not happening even though I've tried catching with 'Exception', 'system.io.IOException' or 'Throwable' in Java.

What am I doing wrong? Is there other way around? Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Code:

```
MyHardware f = new MyHardware();
f.Connection(DEVICE_IP);
if (f.ConnectionStatus()) {
    try {
        net.sf.jni4net.Ref<java.lang.String> refAmount = new Ref<String>(null),
            refVolume = new Ref<String>(null), refPpu = new Ref<String>(null);

        net.sf.jni4net.Ref<java.lang.Integer> refGrade = new Ref<Integer>(null),
            refHose = new Ref<Integer>(hoseId);

        f.GetLastSnapshot(Id, refAmount, refVolume, refPpu, refGrade, refHose);

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        logger.error("Error connecting device.");
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at MyHardwareThread.send(MyHardwareMsg msg)
   at MyHardwareThread.sendReceive(MyHardwareMsg msg)
   at MyHardwareClass.MyHardware.GetLastSnapshot(Int32 p_iPump, String& p_strAmount, String& p_strVolume, String& p_strPPU, Int32& p_iGrade, Int32& p_iHose)
   at MyHardwareClass.__MyHardware.GetLastSnapshot20(IntPtr __envp, JniLocalHandle __obj, Int32 p_iPump, JniLocalHandle p_strAmount, JniLocalHandle p_strVolume, JniLocalHandle p_strPPU, JniLocalHandle p_iGrade, JniLocalHandle p_iHose)
    at MyHardwareclass.MyHardware.GetLastSnapshot(Native Method)
    at com.mno.MyHardware.pos.controller.pos.PosController.getLastSnapshot(PosController.java:774)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Once the socket has been disconnected, you can only reconnect again asynchronously, and only to a different EndPoint.  BeginConnect must be called on a thread that won't exit until the operation has been completed.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(IPEndPoint remoteEP)
   at MyHardwareThread.connect()
   at MyHardwareThread.mainLoop()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: And your code is ... ?

Comment: please share the code